# What's the usage of Golang static library file?

Tags: go

I see `go install <main package>` will compile the dependency packages into static library files and install them into the `pkg` directory, but the executable doesn't need the library files when running. And I also discover that source file is necessary when compiling.

So, is there any special usage of the static files?

Answer (score 3):

The compiled packages can be reused if you compile something else. This saves time on subsequent compiles. When you recompile you only need to compile the package and the things that depend on it, not its dependencies.

They also contain data used by [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) for autcompleting.